# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/rails.js")

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the jquery gem and have installed everything which removes proton.

I am getting this error and I don't understand why?

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/rails.js")
```

I see it in the log.

Any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just fixed a similar problem -- after updating my bundle (including jquery-rails) and running `rails generate jquery:install` (updating jquery itself). As far as I understand, rails.js is now replaced by jquery_ujs.js (I'm not sure it is a smart move though).

You should go on and eliminate any references to rails.js in your app, two possible places to look in are:

`config/application.rb` — you can probably remove the `config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)` line completely

and

`app/views/layouts/application.*` — you should have a `!= javascript_include_tag :defaults` line there and *not* references to `jquery` or `rails`.

Comment: removing the line (i.e commenting it) fixed the problem. Thanks a lot Costa

Comment: Didn't completely work for me, in the end I ran rake `rails:update` which solved it.

Answer (score 2):

What environment are you running (dev/test/prod) ?
If it's prod, is your Rails app configured to serve the static assets?

Comment: I had to run: RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile