# Routing error while searching for javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, heroku, asset-pipeline, thin

My app worked a few days ago.
I have switched to 'thin' from webrick

now I get

```
2011-12-28T07:08:53+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery.livequery-6725741b06c676d9173d5056b277caeb.js"):
```

I saw on other question that they were told to set this to true

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
```

but heroku recommends against that.

I have tried both using rake assets:precompile locally and then pushing and also without it and let heroku precompile.
Both give same error

1. How do I make sure the javascripts are served, compiled and available?
2. Why is the error occuring?

I'm using rails 3.1.3 on cedar, Latest Thin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435080/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-javascripts-rails-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the question [Rails 3.1 asset precompilation - include all javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278029/rails-3-1-asset-precompilation)

so.. problem solved