# Ruby on Rails 4.0.1 app is not able to access my stylesheets in development. How to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There were a few similar questions, but no clear solutions, and I was unable to resolve the issue.

The errors seem to begin when it starts to try to access my stylesheets. The only odd thing I have done to the app recently is place the images in the public folder, because it was unable to access them in the asset pipeline. However, the style sheets were working for about a day. Then it all broke down. Here is the log when I start a rails server:

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.1 application starting in development on localhost
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-01-08 19:55:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-01-08 19:55:25] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32]
[2014-01-08 19:55:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=12384 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 19:55:31 -0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM
"schema_migrations"
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_recent.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (8.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (12.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 49.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 19:55:31
-0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application
.css"):
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
all'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `
call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
start_thread'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescu
es/layout (74.0ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 19:55:31 -
0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application
.js"):
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
all'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `
call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
start_thread'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescu
es/layout (70.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refers here.

May this routin errors caused because of some problems which described in the following post.

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435080/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-javascripts-rails-js)

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I think I may have broken other things in the course of debugging this, so I have decided to recreate the app. A lesson to me to use version control with github. Good lesson to learn early.