# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches “/javascripts/defaults.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everything seems to be working fine, the profile get created and the
company address gets saved but I would like to make it so that this
error is not thrown. I imagine that this is a routing issue, but I
honestly am not certain of that. Anyone have any ideas about what is
happening and how to stop it from throwing these errors? Thanks,

Comment: please upload your code so others can help you more

Answer (score 0):

There is not much detail in your question but maybe this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435080/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-javascripts-rails-js) can help you.